# About calculating the RHP zeros frequency in case of PSFB and Buck converter

Tags: buck, cutoff-frequency

Currently I am doing the regulation of a PSFB converter in CCM.

I have reached the phase of dimensioning the parameters of a PI corrector (Kp and Ki). To do this, I need to choose the value of the cut-off frequency to ensure the stability of the system and have the desired phase margin.

I did some research and according to the literature it is better to ensure this condition for a better value of the cut-off frequency:

3 to 5 f(resonance) < f(cutoff) < 1/3*f(RHP_z)

How to calculate the value of RHP zeros frequency in case of PSFB converter and Buck converter? What formula should I use?

Comment: Break it down to its behavioral essence and apply state space averaging and linearization to find the small signal control-to-output transfer function (one way.) Low phase margins will mean sluggish response, so you need to improve that. Probably by placing zeros around the converter double-pole frequency to nullify their phase reduction effect, with poles placed at w-ESR (if that's a thing) and w-RHP and then a low freq pole 'somewhere' (maybe an integrator to reduce steady state error.) And then be careful about the DC gain. I'm leaving this for others, though. You don't write enough.

Comment: A buck converter doesn't have a RHP zero, and I don't think the conventional PSFB converter would either.  The RHP zero happens in boost or flyback because an increase in the duty cycle temporarily causes the output voltage to drop.

Comment: Thank you so much for your responses!!